# Event viewer log, administrative event error. An unhandled exception has occurred. Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, exception, error-handling

So I had a question before about the 500 internal server error, and after days of trying to find the problem I think I found it in the event log.

But the problem I got right now is that I can't really read / understand what it says and where I have to look in the code. Because the eventdata is just so huge.

Since I'm new to this I really don't want to leak anything so I don't know if I should post the full error, if someone can tell me what part of the error I can share I'll do it so that someone can maybe help me. Here is a part of the error (eventdata):

```
   3005 
   An unhandled exception has occurred 

   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where [TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LoginPartial_cshtml.Execute () at d: \ inetpub \ wwwmlroot \ TestMap \ Views \ Shared \ _LoginPartial : line 30 at (and it just keeps on going with more at)
```

There is a lot more information of course, can someone help me and tell me what I can share? So that somenone can help me with the error.

I think it has something to do with execute() maybe?

Comment: From the error, source parameter is null and source is the enumerable. Where did this error happen, can you share these code?

Comment: @Karney. i shared it on a other question on my profile,